# How to skip further data in file

Tags: c, file, text, fgets

I want to read from a (.txt) file's line just 255 bytes (symbols, numbers, whitespaces) and skip the further ones. If there are less than 255 bytes, then read them all, if there are more than 255 bytes, just the first 255 bytes. I am using **fgets(string, BUFFER_SIZE (which is 255), myFile).** But my file reads all symbols of that line, even if there is more than 255.

**My reading loop**

```
    while(fgets(string, BUFFER_SIZE, input))
    {
        fprintf(output, "%s", string);
    }
```

Comment: I believe that is because you are looping.

Comment: @Jason there could be more lines, than one. So I have to loop somehow.

Comment: Oh, well in that case, maybe just read the whole line and only print max 255?  Edit: To which you can do `%.*s` format string to send length first or just use `fwrite`.

Comment: So, you want to read the first 255 characters of each line until EOF?

Comment: Something like `if (string[strlen(string) -1] != '\n') /*we did not read the whole line */ while (fgetc(input) != '\n');`?

Comment: @RohanBari Yes. Exactly

Comment: @Jason Then I think I have to use fseek() to jump to next line

Comment: How do you know where it is without reading it =]

Comment: @Jason So then I should read char by char, to know where the '\n' is?

Comment: Me personally, yes.  I would.  It can be done with `fgets`/`fwrite` and a bigger buffer as well.  I prefer `fgetc`/`fputc` for simplicity and less edge cases.

Comment: Files don't have lines in them, only bytes (which we can treat as ASCII characters). What you're trying to do is print up to 255 characters, from the file but a \n character resets the counter so it prints another 255 characters after the \n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the fastest solution, but I found almost all simple file operations in C can be done with simple `fgetc`/`fputc` loops.  This way, there is no need to worry about buffers... at all.

```
int n = 0;
int c = fgetc(input);
while (c != EOF) {
   if (c == '\n') {
       n = 0;
   } else if (n >= 255) {
       c = fgetc(input);  // << SNEAKY EDIT
       continue;
   }
   n += 1;
   putc(c);
   c = fgetc(input);
}
```

By the way, I just typed this in here, so not tested.